# can a device act as group owner and client simultaneously?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

As the wifi direct does not scale well beyond 3 clients connected to a group i was thinking of creating a tree structure where there is a main root (group owner) which has two clients .
These clients act as group owner for two other clients each thus enabling connection between them all.

So i want to know if there is a way to enable a device to act as a client in one wifip2p group and as a group owner in another group both running simultaneously.

Would prefer using android 15 api

Comment: Never thought about 'daisy-chaining' like this but it sounds promising. I suppose you could use threads for every instance of client and server you needed running on multiple devices. Please share how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't be connected to multiple groups on the same device.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is not possible because when a device becomes a Group Owner it assigns itself an IP of `192.168.49.1`. So if a device has to be group owner as well as client of a group this brings in the contradiction of having two group owners in the same group and both of them cannot have the IP = `192.168.49.1`, hence there can only be just one group owner in a group.

Thus, in simple words.. **NO it is not possible to have a device behave as group owner and client at the same time.**